# ROS indigo Installation Dependency issue

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS Indigo in ubuntu 14.04.The link for installation is

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

When I give the following install command in my terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

the output messages i get is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-rosdep : Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried

```
apt-get -f install
```

and got

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

So I tried with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then i get an error

```
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.0-1_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.0-100_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.0-100_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.0-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.0-100_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`

I also tried several steps which i got from other forums

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Nothing worked out.

Anybody have encountered or have an idea on how to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310473/ros-indigo-installation-dependency-issue/) by [rosusernli](https://answers.ros.org/users/31974/rosusernli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2018-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:\

> has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up

this seems to tell us that your `dpkg` is too old. Try running a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade dpkg`. Then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be a duplicate of #q299091.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosusernli](https://answers.ros.org/users/31974/rosusernli/) on 2018-12-12**:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade dpkg` gives

```
python-rosdep : Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.4.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
It seems strange that an update of `dpkg` -- a base Debian package -- would result in errors about `python-rosdep`.

What is the general status of `apt` on your system?

Do you have "broken packages"?

**Comment by [rosusernli](https://answers.ros.org/users/31974/rosusernli/) on 2018-12-13**:
Thanks for the tip. It worked !!!

I removed the broken and residual packages using `sudo apt-get remove --purge $(sudo dpkg -l | grep "^iU" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')` and `dpkg --list |grep "^rc" | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs sudo dpkg --purge`

I was able to do the  dpkg upgrade and install